# Date Format c in timestamp?

Tags: php

Как преобразовать формат даты тип "C" в timestamp?

```
2019-05-15T22:00:00+0000
```

Пробую

```
strtotime('2019-05-15T22:00:00+0000');// 1557957600 получается
```

Но когда обратно форматируется

```
date('c', 1557957600 );// Получается 2019-05-16T01:00:00+03:00
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`2019-05-15 22:00:00` в `UTC` это и есть `2019-05-16 01:00:00` в `UTC+3`, всё совершенно верно считается и форматируется.

Если вы хотели спросить, почему `date` выводит данные в `UTC+3` - то именно это `date` делать и должна, она намеренно форматирует указанный unixtime в вашем локальном часовом поясе. Если вам не нужно это преобразование - то для этого предназначена [`gmdate`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php), оперирующая всегда в `UTC`.

```
php > echo date('c', 1557957600 );
2019-05-16T01:00:00+03:00
php > echo gmdate('c', 1557957600 );
2019-05-15T22:00:00+00:00
```